# Simulating server-side group and sort in Azure table storage

Tags: sorting, azure, grouping, azure-table-storage

I have a table to which I add records whenever the user views a particular resource. The key fields are

- Username
- Resource
- Date Viewed

On a history page of my app, I want to present a set number (e.g., top 5) of the user's most recently viewed Resources, but I want to group by Resource, so that if some were viewed several times, only the most recent of each one is shown.

To be clear, if the raw data looked like this:

```
UserA | ResourceA | Jan 1
UserA | ResourceA | Jan 2
UserA | ResourceB | Jan 3
UserA | ResourceA | Jan 4
...
```

...only the bottom two records would appear in the history page.

I know you can get server-side chronological sorting by using a string derived from the date in the PartitionKey or RowKey fields.

I also see that you could enable a crude grouping mechanism by using Username and Resource as your PartitionKey and RowKey fields, and then using Insert-or-update, to maintain a table in which you kept pointers for the most recent value for each combination. However, *those* records wouldn't be sorted chronologically.

Is there any way to design a set of tables so that I can get the data I need without retrieving tons of extra entities and sorting on the client? I'm willing to get elaborate with the design if that's what it takes. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please share more details about your design. Also please describe what data do you want to fetch.

Comment: @GauravMantri Thanks for the reply. As I said above, the table contains three important fields. You can consider the Resource field to simply be a string identifier, so we have Username (string), ResourceName (string), and DateViewed (DateTimeOffset). I want to get a list of the top n most recently accessed ResourceNames, grouped by ResourceName, along with the time of the most recent access. So if the table has 200 records for Resource A and 200 for Resource B (viewed at many different times), I would fetch the most recent lines for Resource A and B. Simple in SQL but tricky with Azure!

Answer (score 0):

First, I would strongly recommend that you read this excellent [`Azure Storage Table Design Guide: Designing Scalable and Performant Tables`](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-table-design-guide/) document from Storage team.

Yes, I would agree that it is somewhat tricky with Azure Table Storage but it is doable :).

**What you have to do is keep multiple copies of the same data. Each copy will serve a different purpose.**

Considering the scenario where you want to fetch most recent lines for Resource A and B, here's what your entity structure would look like:

- `PartitionKey`: Date/Time (in Ticks) reversed i.e. DateTime.MaxValue.Ticks - LastAccessedDateTime.Ticks. Reverse ticks is required to that most recent entries will show up on the top of the table.
- `RowKey`: Resource name.
- `AccessDate`: Indicates the last access date/time.
- `User`: Name of the user who accessed that resource.

So when you are interested in just finding out most recently used resources, you could start fetching records from the top.

In short, **your data storage approach should be primarily governed by how you want to fetch the data**. It would even mean you will have to save the same data multiple times.

**UPDATE**

As discussed in the comments below, Table Service doesn't directly support `Server Side Grouping`. This is something that you would need to do on your own. What you could do is create a separate table to store the access counts. As and when the resources are accessed, you basically either insert a new record in that table or update the count for that resource in that table.

Assuming you're always interested in finding out resource access count within a date/time range, here's what your entity structure would look like:

- `PartitionKey`: Date/Time (in Ticks). The precision would depend on your reporting requirement. For example, if you want to maintain access counts by day then your precision would be a day.
- `RowKey`: Resource name.
- `AccessCount`: This field will constantly update as and when a resource is accessed.
- `LastAccessDateTime`: This field will denote when a resource was last accessed.

For updating access counts, I would recommend that you make use of a background process. Basically in this approach, as a resource is accessed you add a message in a queue. This message will have resource name and date/time resource was last accessed. Then have a background process poll this queue and fetch messages. As the messages are received, you first get the current count and last access date/time for that resource. If no records are found, you simply insert a record in this table with count as 1. If a record is found then you compare the date/time from the table with the date/time sent in the message. If the date/time from the table is smaller than the date/time sent in the message, you update both count (increase that by 1) and last access date/time. If the date/time from the table is more than the date/time sent in the message, you only update the count.

Now to find most accessed resources in a time span, you simply query this table. Assuming there are limited number of resources (say in 100s), you can get this information from the table with at least 1 request. Since you're dealing with small amount of data, you can simply download this data on the client side and order it anyway you see fit. However to see the access details for a particular resource, you would have to fetch detailed data (1000 entities at a time).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have read the document, and I am currently storing my data like that. The problem is that, without grouping, there's no way to know how many rows you'll need to retrieve. For example, the user might have accessed Resource A once or 1000 times. In order to get the most recent access records for N resources, you might need the top N rows, or you might need some arbitrarily higher number--could be N+1, could be N+100,000. Is the only approach really to take some rows, examine them, then take some more, and so on? It seems so inefficient.

Comment: Do you want to find out how many times a resource has been used?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I think I've explained it pretty well. Are you reading my posts? No, I don't want the number of times a resource has been accessed. As I've said, I want the most recently accessed N resources, **grouped by resource** (so that there are no duplicate resource names). Using your approach, there is no way to know how many rows should be fetched to get this data. I'm not sure how I can explain this more clearly.

Comment: Sorry, my bad :(. So there's no direct server-side grouping available with Azure tables. One thing you could do is keep the access counts separately (may be in a separate table) and as an when a resource is accessed, you can update the count there. When you need to fetch the resources, you can first find the count from that table and then fetch that many rows from the table containing detailed data.

Comment: Thanks for the idea. I hadn't thought of this. It feels like it could be on the right track, but it still doesn't solve the issue. Consider 10 resources, each of which has been accessed in some unknown order 100 times. Our goal is to retrieve the most recently accessed n resources (let's say 5) and the date of the last access. If we consult the table you mention, would correctly learn that there are 1000 entries in the full access table. But that doesn't save us any effort from just downloading the entire main table to begin with. Maybe there's just no good solution right now.

Comment: I think this solution will work if you have limited number of resources (say less than 1000). In a single request, table service will return at most 1000 entities (in this case the resource group access count). Let me update my answer to explain my thoughts around grouping.

Answer (score -1):

Part of your brain might still be unconsciously trapped in relational-table design paradigms, I'm still getting to grips with that issue myself.

Rather than think of table storage as a database table (with the "query-ability" that goes with it) try visualizing it in more simple (dumb) terms.

A design problem I'm working on now is storing financial transaction data, and I want to know what the total $ amount of these transactions are.  Because Azure table storage doesn't (yet?) offer aggregate functions I can't simply go .Sum().  To get around that I'm going to:

- Sum the values of the transactions in my app before I pass them to azure.
- I'll then pass that the result of the sum into azure as a separate piece of information, called `RunningTotal`.
- Later on I can just return `RunningTotal` rather than pulling down all the transactions, and I can repeat the process by increment the value of `RunningTotal` each time i get new transactions.

Of course there are risks to this but the app is a personal one so the risk level is low and manageable, at least as a proof-of-concept.

Perhaps you can use a similar approach for the design of your system: compute useful values in advance.  I'll almost be using table storage as a long-term cache rather than a database.